# Changing currentTime in HTML audio when source is remote?

Tags: javascript, audio

I have a video and audio element in a web page, and based on an action the audio element will get played at the same time position as the video is currently at. This works when the audio is local, but fails when the audio track is on a remote server. The end result is the audio track ends up playing from the start.

The HTML:

```html
  <video id="videoTrack1" autoplay muted loop @mouseenter="onPlayAudio(1)" @mouseleave="onStopAudio(1)">
    <source src="/videos/video.mp4" type="video/mp4" />
  </video>
  <audio id="audioTrack1" >
    <source src="/videos/audio.m4a" type="audio/mp4" />
  </audio>
```

The JS:

```js
onPlayAudio (trackId) {
  const videoPlayer = document.getElementById(`videoTrack${trackId}`);
  const audioPlayer = document.getElementById(`audioTrack${trackId}`);

  if (videoPlayer && audioPlayer) {
    audioPlayer.onended = this.onAudioEnded;
    audioPlayer.currentTime = target.currentTime;
    audioPlayer.play();
  }
},
```

I did trying waiting for the play to start, as some places suggested, but this didn't change anything:

```js
const onPlaying = () => {
  audioPlayer.currentTime = videoTrack.currentTime;
  audioPlayer.removeEventListener('playing', onPlaying);
};

audioPlayer.addEventListener('playing', onPlaying);
```

Is there anything special I need to be doing for setting the `currentTime`, if the track is not local?

Just for clarification:

- local: relative path on the server where the JS is being loaded from, which is local to the web page requested
- remote: different server to the loaded web page

Comment: what do you mean by "local" vs "remove server" - surely the audio always comes from a "remote server"

Comment: Check that your server accepts [Range requests](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Range_requests).

Comment: @Bravo There are all kinds of use cases where the audio would come from local...

Comment: @AndreM Yeah, what Kaiido said.  Also, you can use your browser's developer tools to see how it is responding to range requests.

Comment: @Bravo relative path on the server where the JS is running, vs a different server referenced by https/http

Comment: the JS you're talking about is running in the browser regardless, so, still makes no sense @AndreM